# Join multiple secondary tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have following tables:

```
master_table(id, col1, col2, discriminator_col)

join_table1(m_id, v_id)
value_table1(id, val)

join_table2(m_id, v_id)
value_table2(id, val)
```

there is single master table and several value tables joined to master table via join tables. Value tables contain single scalar value for each master_table row. Values from separate values tables are placed into descendant entities, so there are one MasterEntity and several Child1Entity, Child2Entity etc.

I would like not to create a separate entity for each value_table, just for each ChildEntity and somehow join value table to that entity.

**MasterEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(...) // not sure what type of inheritance to use
public class MasterEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String col1;

    private String col2;
}
```

**Child1Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Child1Entity extends MasterEntity {

    // need to get value_table1.val column here

}
```

I could create entity for value_table and add many-to-one relation to `Child1Entity`, but if it is possible to avoid I would like to do that.

I tried to add two secondary tables (join_table1, value_table1) to `Child1Entity`, but I can not join `join_table1` with `value_table1`, just with `master_table`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `@Inheritance`, you can't have those `join_tables`. With those join tables, your model says:

- one value can belong to multiple master rows
- one master row can belong to multiple value rows

If you just want: 1 master belongs to 1 value row, than use this:

```
master (id, ...)
value1 (masterId, ...)
value2 (masterId, ...)
```

With `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)`.

For more information have a look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

**BUT:** Whenever you use `@Inheritance` you will have to create a separate `@Entity` class for everything.

---

If you really need the 5 table layout from above, use `@ManyToMany`.

---

Basically JPA is made for Mapping Java Objects to SQL Tables, not the other way round ;) If you need to do thing's which aren't possible using JPA (or too complicated), you can always use JDBC and craft your queries and Entity mappings by hand.